# MySQL / PHP, ForEach Loops slow

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new at stackoverflow, please accept my apologies for the long question. I have a large database of a retail outlet. We wanted to prepare a report to get the opening and closing balances of products, products have batch number and every batch has unique serial number which are assigned to multiple locations. The challenge is to get the opening balances of each batch of the selected product for each warehouse location. If location isn't specified in report filter then the report should give the result for each location's selected product and all of its batches.

I get all the locations using PHP / PDO and loop through it, with in the first loop i get all the batches against the selected product and with in the batches loop i first get the opening balance (which is calculated like, sum of quantity before the from date filter), i then calculate the quantity received of that product's batch in that location (sum of quantity received within the from and to date filter), then quantity sold or quantity moved to other warehouses (sum of quantity moved to other warehouse within the selected from and to date filter).

I can now calculate the closing balance as i have all the values. This runs fine but when the query runs for 20 warehouses and there are almost 20+ batches for a single product, the report takes ages to process and MySQL CPU usage goes upto 200%.

I tried to optimize the queries, my tables are properly indexed. Tables have alot of data. millions of records. I need advise on how to improve my code or methods, what am I doing wrong and how can I make the report faster.

I am using code igniter for my application and following is the code.

```
foreach($locations as $loc){
    //if batch is selected put it in array
    if($query_array['batch_no'] != ''){
        $batches[] = $query_array['batch_no'];
    }else{
    // or get all batches from the inventory table for the location
        $this->db->select('distinct(batch_no)');
        $this->db->from('product_details');
        $this->db->where('product_id',$query_array ['product']);
        $this->db->where('warehouse_id',$loc);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $batches[] =  $row->batch_no;
        }
        $query->free_result();
    }

    foreach($batches as $batch){

        //GIN IN Opening Balance
        $this->db->select('IFNULL(SUM(gi.qty),0) as gin_in',FALSE);
        $this->db->from('gin as g');
        $this->db->join('gin_items as gi','gi.gin_id=g.id');
        $this->db->where('gi.product_id',$query_array ['product']);
        $this->db->where('DATE(g.creation_date) < ',$query_array ['date_from']);
        $this->db->where('g.to_location_id', $loc);
        $this->db->where_in('gi.batch_no',$batch);
        $this->db->where_in('gi.status',2);
        $this->db->where('g.status',3);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()==1)
        {
            $var1=$query->row()->gin_in;
            $query->free_result();
        }

        // SUM (Return Invoices for a specific product, for this particular store, 
        // before this date range) -> $var2
        $this->db->select('IFNULL(SUM(ii.qty),0) as sale_return_in',FALSE);
        $this->db->from('return_sales_invoice rs');
        $this->db->join('return_invoice_items as ii','ii.invoice_id=rs.id');
        $this->db->where('ii.medicine_id',$query_array ['product']);
        $this->db->where_in('ii.batch_no',$batch);
        $this->db->where_in('rs.location_id',$loc);
        $this->db->where('rs.dated < ',$query_array ['date_from']);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            $var2=$query->row()->sale_return_in;
            $query->free_result();
        }


        //SUM (Sales Invoices of a specific product, from this particular store, 
        // before this date range) -> $var3
        $this->db->select('IFNULL(SUM(ii.qty),0) as sale_out',FALSE);
        $this->db->from('sales_invoice si');
        $this->db->join('invoice_items as ii','ii.invoice_id=si.id');

        $this->db->where('ii.medicine_id',$query_array ['product']);
        $this->db->where_in('ii.batch_no',$batch);
        $this->db->where_in('si.location_id',$loc);
        $this->db->where('si.dated < ',$query_array ['date_from']);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            $var3=$query->row()->sale_out;
            $query->free_result();
        }

        // SUM (GIN of a specific product, from this particular store, 
        // before this date range) -> $var4
        // if from location then minis stock 
        $this->db->select('IFNULL(SUM(gi.qty),0) as gin_out',FALSE);
        $this->db->from('gin as g');
        $this->db->join('gin_items as gi','gi.gin_id=g.id');
        $this->db->where('DATE(g.creation_date) < ',$query_array ['date_from']);
        $this->db->where('gi.product_id',$query_array ['product']);
        $this->db->where_in('gi.batch_no',$batch);
        $this->db->where_in('g.from_location_id',$loc);
        $this->db->where('gi.status',2);
        $this->db->where('g.status',3);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            $var4=$query->row()->gin_out;
            $query->free_result();
        }
        $op_bal = ($var1 + $var2) - ($var3 + $var4);

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        $where_from = "DATE(g.creation_date) >='" . $query_array ['date_from'] . "'";
        $where_to = "DATE(g.creation_date)  <='" . $query_array ['date_to'] . "'";

        $rs_where_from = "DATE(rs.creation_date) >='" . $query_array ['date_from'] . "'";
        $rs_where_to = "DATE(rs.creation_date)  <='" . $query_array ['date_to'] . "'";

        $si_where_from = "DATE(si.creation_date) >='" . $query_array ['date_from'] . "'";
        $si_where_to = "DATE(si.creation_date)  <='" . $query_array ['date_to'] . "'";

        //GIN IN Opening Balance
        $this->db->select('IFNULL(SUM(gi.qty),0) as gin_in',FALSE);
        $this->db->from('gin as g');
        $this->db->join('gin_items as gi','gi.gin_id=g.id');
        $this->db->where($where_from);
        $this->db->where($where_to);
        $this->db->where('gi.product_id',$query_array ['product']);
        $this->db->where_in('gi.batch_no',$batch);
        $this->db->where_in('g.to_location_id', $loc);
        $this->db->where('g.status',3);
        $this->db->where('gi.status',2);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            $g_stock_in=$query->row()->gin_in;
            $query->free_result();
        }

        // SUM (Return Invoices for a specific product, for this particular store, 
        // before this date range) -> $var2
        $this->db->select('IFNULL(SUM(ii.qty),0) as sale_return_in',FALSE);
        $this->db->from('return_sales_invoice rs');
        $this->db->join('return_invoice_items as ii','ii.invoice_id=rs.id');
        $this->db->where('ii.medicine_id',$query_array ['product']);
        $this->db->where($rs_where_from);
        $this->db->where($rs_where_to);                 
        $this->db->where_in('ii.batch_no',$batch);
        $this->db->where_in('rs.location_id',$loc);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            $s_stock_in=$query->row()->sale_return_in;
            $query->free_result();
        }


        //SUM (Sales Invoices of a specific product, from this particular store, 
        // before this date range) -> $var3
        $this->db->select('IFNULL(SUM(ii.qty),0) as sale_out',FALSE);
        $this->db->from('sales_invoice si');
        $this->db->join('invoice_items as ii','ii.invoice_id=si.id');
        $this->db->where('ii.medicine_id',$query_array ['product']);
        $this->db->where_in('ii.batch_no',$batch);
        $this->db->where_in('si.location_id',$loc);
        $this->db->where($si_where_from);
        $this->db->where($si_where_to);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            $s_stock_out=$query->row()->sale_out;
            $query->free_result();
        }

        // SUM (GIN of a specific product, from this particular store, 
        // before this date range) -> $var4
        // if from location then minis stock 
        $this->db->select('IFNULL(SUM(gi.qty),0) as gin_out',FALSE);
        $this->db->from('gin as g');
        $this->db->join('gin_items as gi','gi.gin_id=g.id');
        $this->db->where($where_from);
        $this->db->where($where_to);
        $this->db->where('gi.product_id',$query_array ['product']);
        $this->db->where_in('gi.batch_no',$batch);
        $this->db->where_in('g.from_location_id',$loc);
        $this->db->where('g.status',3);
        $this->db->where('gi.status',2);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            $g_stock_out=$query->row()->gin_out;
            $query->free_result();
        }
        $qty_in=$g_stock_in+$s_stock_in;
        $qty_out=$g_stock_out+$s_stock_out;

        $productName=$this->getProductName($query_array ['product']);
        $locationName=$this->getLocationName($loc);

        $data [] = array (
            'location' => $locationName,
            'product' => $productName, 
            'batchno' => $batch , 
            'op_bal' => $res['op_bal'] , 
            'qty_in' => $qty_in, 
            'qty_out' => $qty_out,
            'cl_bal' => ($res['op_bal'] + $qty_in ) - $qty_out
        );      

    }
}
return $data;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! A quick constructive critique of your question: the code example is quite long, and may discourage volunteers from trying to puzzle it out. Also, query-performance questions usually get best results if you show the data table and index structures, and the actual queries rather than the Code Igniter code.  Finally, a numeric username rather than your own name further discourages people from investing time in you: many such users never come back.  Again, welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You recognize that you're doing a lot of stuff in this report program.  In particular you're making lots of single-result-row queries. That's often considered harmful to performance, compared with writing fewer queries that return a row for each item.

One possible solution to your problem: Run the report program at night, and don't sweat the lousy performance. You'll get the job done. This sort of overnight batch run is fairly common in real-world situations.

Another solution: treat the database as a machine to return tables, not just values. Refactor your queries to return multiple results. You'll end up with far fewer queries and you'll be able to take advantage of the DBMS's query planner to pull lots of information at once.  For example, instead of looping on location in php, get MySQL to do that.

This will give you a list of batches, warehouses and products, one row each.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT batch_no, warehouse_id, product
      FROM product_details
     ORDER BY batch_no, warehouse_id, product
```

Next, I guess this query will give you one of your required results, but for all the batches, warehouses, and products.  "I guess" because you haven't disclosed your schema or business rules.  This query comes from combining the first two queries in your program.

```
SELECT SUM(gi.qty) gin_in, p.batch_no, p.warehouse_id, p.product 
  FROM product_details p
  JOIN gin g        ON g.to_location_id = p.warehouse_id
  JOIN gin_items gi ON gi.gin_id = g.id AND gi.product_id = p.product
 WHERE DATE(g.creation_date) < $date_from
   AND g.status = 3
 GROUP BY p.batch_no, p.warehouse_id, p.product
```

You get the idea: make your queries return lots of rows, rather than running the query a gazillion times only to return a single row each time.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into the question. Running the report at night is a good idea for now till i try out the other suggestions you gave.